# (iOS12.2)Could not return to local page using Wkwebview after redirecting from the remote authentication site

Tags: javascript, html, ios, wkwebview

Currently I am developing a hybrid app that uses Wkwebview, and experiencing some problems on redirecting from an external authentication site to local page on iOS 12.2. It used to work fine before iOS 12.2, and seems like the new security update on webview are effecting the problem.
Does anyone know how to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have the same the problem. return to local page after redirecting any remote page.